# Splitting up data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am splitting up a string and i come up with the correct answer with this query

```
select 

      SUBSTRING(unit1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', unit1) - 1)Qty
      ,SUBSTRING(unit1, CHARINDEX(' ', unit1) + 1, LEN(unit1))Units

      --,unit1
      from 

      (SELECT  
      SUBSTRING(Description], CHARINDEX(': ', [Description]) + 2, LEN([Description])) unit1
  FROM Table 
  )
```

For this data this query splits up the Description in to just the qut and the units that is in the Description

```
Description                     Qty   Units 
Container Capacity: 5 Gallon    5     Gallon    
Container Capacity: 1 Liter     1     Liter 
Container Capacity: 1 quart     1     quart 
Container Capacity: 0.5 Liter   0.5   Liter 
Container Capacity: 20 Liter    20    Liter 
Container Capacity: 236 ml      236   ml    
Container Capacity: 250 ml      250   ml    
Container Capacity: 3.5 oz      3.5   oz    
Container Capacity: 4 Liter     4     Liter 
Container Capacity: 5 Liter     5     Liter 
Container Capacity: 55 Liter    55    Liter 
Container Capacity: 60 Liter    60    Liter 
Container Capacity: 1 pint      1     pint
```

I guess my question is is there a better way to do this it just seams like i should be able to cut the inner select statement out and get to the correct form from one select statement.
Thank you very much for any help

Comment: You could nest the substring statements, but it would start looking really ugly.

Comment: The best way would be to not have to do this at all, which means storing that information (which seems important to me) in their own columns. Is that something that would be feasible?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on non-standard the usage of `[...]` for an identifier and the `charindex` function.

Comment: DaaaahWhoosh ya i tried that and it does get ugly

Comment: Ellesedil-- ya i am not sure what you mean i start out with the first column and i need to end up with the last two

Comment: So the data you're original data has a column named "Description" in a table named "TABLE"? And is the data in that column a string like "Container Capacity: 5 Gallon"?